# Strange behavior on state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a form with a questionary component, this questionary componente allow me to add sections of the questionary as you can see in the following image:

[image]

also as you can see I have a button to delete each section, here is the button on my section component:

```
<button
    className="circle-button delete-section"
    onClick={handleDeleteSection}
    data-section-id={sectionId}
    type="button"
  >
    &times;
  </button>
```

This button has a `handleDeleteSection` and this method is on the parent component and here is the method:

```
const handleDeleteSection = (event) => {
    const idToDelete = event.target.dataset.sectionId;
    const updatedSections = questionaryState.sections.filter(
      (section) => section.sectionId !== idToDelete
    );
    // update the state with new sections
    setQuestionaryState((questionaryState) => ({
      ...questionaryState,
      sections: updatedSections,
    }));
  };
```

but updatedSections is always with a wrong lenght e.g:
if I click on delete button of 'section 1' the updatedSections length is 0
if I click on delete button of 'section 3' the updatedSections length is 2
if I click on delete button of 'section 4' the updatedSections length is 3

but as you can see in the following image, the questionaryState.sections has 4 elements:

[image]

Any Idea or suggestion of what is going on here, becuase without the proper array of section I can not delete the section when the user press the delete button

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT: UPLOAD VIDEO

Here is a video with an example: https://vimeo.com/469746051

Comment: I am assuming you have you checked that the `sectionId` value you are assigning to each `data-section-id` property is valid? I.e. it's not off by one?

Comment: are you using components or hooks ?

Comment: @Andris yes the id is valid

Comment: @SpringerF both

Comment: Why pass a function to `setQuestionaryState` when all you need is `setQuestionaryState({...questionaryState, sections: updatedSections})`

Comment: @kimobrian254 I also try that way and same behavior

Comment: Can you add some code where you try to display the length? Maybe some other code is affecting the whole flow. I'll also add something like this for debugging(https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect): `useDeepCompareEffect(() => { console.log(questionaryState.sections.length), [questionaryState]}`. This is to log the length after every state update

Comment: @kimobrian254 I just upload a video in case you want to see a real example https://vimeo.com/user40777412/review/469746051/389fb58b0b

Comment: @Jean I also editted my comment above in case you wanna try editing with the suggestion I added.

Comment: The link doesn't open, it says `Sorry, we couldn’t find that page`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223290/discussion-between-kimobrian254-and-jean).

Answer (score 0):

You are  using setQuestionaryState (state) hook in a wrong way ,  you should update the state after removing the clicked element by passing an object , and not using a callback function : as below

```
const handleDeleteSection = (event) => {
    const idToDelete = event.target.dataset.sectionId;
    const updatedSections = questionaryState.sections.filter(
      (section) => section.sectionId !== idToDelete
    );

    // update the state with new sections
    setQuestionaryState({
      ...questionaryState,
      sections: updatedSections,
    });
};
```

Comment: Does not work either, for example I have 4 sections if I delete the first one all the sections are delete te because updateSections is 1 when I click on the first section but it supposed to have a length of 4

Comment: I just upload a video if you want to see a real example

Comment: so the problem is in the filter function ! 
what if you click on the first and , add `console.log("-->";section.sectionId,idToDelete)` inside the filter function , what it shows !

Comment: The problem is the questionaryState, but I can't figure it out why, for example questionaryState always have the state before I create the sections so imagine that I have 4 sections if I trigger handleDeleteSection from section 1 questionaryState.section.length is 0 even though I have 4 sections, but if I trigger from the last one questionaryState.section.length is 3 and I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

you need to spread your state before you filter to prevent passing a ref it safer that as it creates a new array  , and then pass the filtered results directly to your "sections" in set state

```
const handleDeleteSection = (event) => {
    const idToDelete = event.target.dataset.sectionId;
    const sectonsTemp =  [...questionaryState.sections]
    const updatedSections =sectonsTemp.filter(
      (section) => section.sectionId !== idToDelete
    );
    // update the state with new sections
   setQuestionaryState({
      ...questionaryState,
      sections: updatedSections ,
    });

  };
```

Comment: That's unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
const handleDeleteSection = (idToDelete) => {
  const updatedSections = questionaryState.sections.filter(
    (section) => section.sectionId !== idToDelete
  );

  setQuestionaryState({
    sections: updatedSections
  });
};
```

HTML

```
<button
  className="circle-button delete-section"
  onClick={() => handleDeleteSection(sectionId)}
  type="button"
>
  &times;
</button>
```